# Javascript Object reference from Array

Tags: javascript, json, object, reference, javascript-objects

I have an object called `o` . I want to assign the elements of an array called `newOb` to the proprieties  of `o` so that any change done with `newObj` will affect `o` . This works fine so far:

```
    let o = {}
    let c = {c:18}
    let newOb = [{a: 55}, {b: 55}]
    o.propA = newOb[0]
    o.propB = newOb[1]
    newOb[0].a++
    console.log(newOb, o)
```

Output:

```
 Array [Object { a: 56 }, Object { b: 55 }] Object { propA: Object { a: 56 }, propB: Object { b: 55 } }
```

Until this:

```
   let o = {}
    let c = {c:18}
    let newOb = [{a: 55}, {b: 55}]
    o.propA = newOb[0]
    o.propB = newOb[1]
    newOb[0] =  c
    console.log(newOb, o)
```

Outputs

```
Array [Object { c: 18 }, Object { b: 55 }] Object { propA: Object { a: 55 }, propB: Object { b: 55 } }
```

When I try to change the element if `newOb`, the properties of `o` is not affected. Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let o = {}
    let c = {c:18}
    let newOb = [{a: 55}, {b: 55}]
    o.propA = a => newOb[0]
    o.propB = a => newOb[1]
    newOb[0] =  c
    console.log(newOb, o.propA(), o.propB());
```